# Overlay div on document.body.appendChild as background

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to use the image generated by https://github.com/qrohlf/trianglify as a background image as the author does on his website (http://qrohlf.com/trianglify/). How do I overlay a div on the document.body.appendChild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Trianglify library provides a `.png()` method we can use to add a dynamically generated image to the page.

This first method simply sets the `document.body.style.backgroundImage` to the generated Trianglify image. In both cases we'll use `window.innerHeight` and `window.innerWidth` to get the height and width of the window when creating the Trianglify image.

```js
// Create the Trianglify image
var pattern = Trianglify({
  height: window.innerHeight,
  width: window.innerWidth,
  cell_size: 30});

document.body.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
document.body.style.backgroundImage =  "url(" + pattern.png() + ")";
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/trianglify/1.0.1/trianglify.min.js"></script>
Here's our HTML body.
```

You could also create an element, and set the Trianglify image as the background on it, to overlay it on the page.

```js
// Create the Trianglify image
var pattern = Trianglify({
  height: window.innerHeight,
  width: window.innerWidth,
  cell_size: 30});


var overlay = document.createElement("div"); 
overlay.style.position = "absolute";
overlay.style.top = "0";
overlay.style.left = "0";
overlay.style.height = "100%";
overlay.style.width = "100%";
overlay.style.opacity = "0.8";

overlay.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
overlay.style.backgroundImage =  "url(" + pattern.png() + ")";

document.body.appendChild(overlay);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/trianglify/1.0.1/trianglify.min.js"></script>
Here's our HTML body.
```